# Como centralizar uma div com position:fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Gostaria de saber se é possível centralizar uma div com o `position:fixed` ? Atualmente tentei centralizar o usando o `margin:0 auto` mas não funcionou... infelizmente como a largura da minha div fixed vai ser dinâmica não posso utilizar o `left` e `margin-left` negativo T.T

Codigo CSS:

```
.container {
    background: #F00;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;    
}

.fixo {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixo"></div>
</div>
```

Segue o codigo com o exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/9d52oyty/

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Se você colocar  `margin-left e right com auto` sem o position centraliza também http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/9d52oyty/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tem duas opções:

JavaScript:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.fixo'),
    w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

container.style.top = (y / 2) - (container.clientHeight / 2) + 'px';
container.style.left = (x / 2) - (container.clientWidth / 2) + 'px';
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/j6qvryz2/1/

CSS:

```
.fixo {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%; left: 50%;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/j6qvryz2/

A versão javascript calcula a altura e largura do ecrã, divide pela metade e subtrai metade da largura ou respectiva altura do elemento.

A versão CSS é aproximada. Dá para ajustar se as medidas forem +/- estáticas. Para browsers modernos a [solução do @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33496/129) é ideal.

---

### Edit:

Em casos em que é necessário dar suporte a browsers antingos sugiro usar feature-detection. Ou seja, detectar se o Browser suporta o `calc()` no CSS ([como o @bfavaretto sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33496/129)), e caso negativo fazer o posicionamento via JavaScript.

Exemplo:

CSS

```
.fixo {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

JavaScript

```
// usando o feature detect do Modrnizer
var calc = (function(){
    var dummy = document.createElement('div');
    var props = ['calc', '-webkit-calc', '-moz-calc', '-o-calc'];
    for (var i=0; i<props.length; ++i) {
        var prop = props[i];
        dummy.style.cssText = 'width:' + prop + '(1px);';
        if (dummy.style.length)
            return prop;
    }
})();

if (!calc) {
    var container = document.querySelector('.fixo'),
        w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

    container.style.top = (y / 2) - (container.clientHeight / 2) + 'px';
    container.style.left = (x / 2) - (container.clientWidth / 2) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, infelizmente  o IE8 me atormenta nesse caso, vou apenas adaptar para meu cenário pratico, mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Comment: @DouglasdosSantos juntei mais info à resposta para corrigir a posição caso o Browser não suporte ´calc()` no CSS como o @bfavaretto sugeriu.

Answer (score 4):

Se o seu browser der [suporte](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) dá para fazer assim:

```
left: calc(50% - 50px);
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/55d4vr5y/</sup>

Ou seja, posicione o div pela esquerda na metade da largura do container menos metade da largura do div fixo.

Comment: Muito obrigado bfvaretto, mas infelizmente tem q funcionar no IE8( saco! ), realmente vou ter que utilizar javascript para resolver mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Se a largura da div vai ser dinâmica, da para fazer apenas com CSS, basta fixar o container com largura de 100%, altura 0 (para as sobras não ficarem por cima dos links da pagina) e alinhar o texto centralizado, e a div com o conteúdo coloca como inline-block e define o restante das propriedades, algo assim:

```
.container {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .fixo {
    display: inline-block;
    background:#000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5s8ae01/)

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra fazer usando apenas CSS: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d52oyty/1/)

Esse é o "truque":

```
top:50%; /* Metade da altura da tela */
left:50%; /* Metade da largura da tela */
margin-top:-25px; /* Metade da altura do elemento */
margin-left:-50px; /* Metade da largura do elemento */
```

Ou com dimensão relativa, usando JS/jQuery: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d52oyty/2/)

```
$('.fixo').css({
    'margin-top' : '-' + ($('.fixo').height()/2) + 'px',
    'margin-left' : '-' + ($('.fixo').width()/2) + 'px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa moderna e que dispensa o uso de JavaScript é a seguinte:

```
.container .fixo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```