# Centralizar um elemento com css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer um pop-up com uma tela de login, porém a `div` de `class="form-login-div"` não está sendo centralizada automaticamente de jeito nenhum.

Alguma ideia?
CSS:

```
.form-login-div-parent{
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  bottom:0;
}
.form-login-div {
  width: 35rem;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  padding:1rem;
  background-color:#0374D6;
}  

.home-container{
    width:30rem;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="home-container">
    <div class="form-login-div-parent">
      <div class="form-login-div">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Endereço de e-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Insira o seu e-mail">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Senha</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Insira a sua senha">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div style="text-align: left;">
              {% if view_bag["erro"] == true %}
            <p style="color: rgb(240, 47, 47); ">{{ view_bag["mensagem"] }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: right;">
              <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <picture>
      <source class="imagem-fundo" media="(max-width: 1140px )" srcset="/static/img/imagemestudante-smartphones-blur.png"
        type="image/png">
      <img class="imagem-fundo" src="/static/img/imagemestudante-full.jpg" alt="Foto de estudantes ao fundo">
    </picture>
  </div>
```

Comment: relacionadas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58614/centralizar-horizontalmente e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33495/como-centralizar-uma-div-com-positionfixed
dá uma pesquisa no site tem muitas perguntas sobre isso

Comment: eu pesquisei nos "perguntas parecidas" mas não encontrei

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, aonde que tu tá mandando centralizar essa div?

Ali no `.form-login-div`, adiciona essas 2 linhas:

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Não sei se é só isso que tu precisa.

Comment: Nesse código em especifico eu já apaguei todas as tentativas, mas vou tentar seu jeito!

Comment: nunca experimentei nem ouvi falar desse transform, obrigado! Funcionou!

Answer (score -2):

Olá! Você pode usar `display: flex` e `justify-content: center` no `.form-login-div-parent` para centralizar na horizontal.

Se quiser na vertical também acrescente o `align-items: center`, e force a altura do parent para 100vh com um `height: 100vh`.

Fiz um exemplo rápido: https://codepen.io/paulofdaniel/pen/abJjpqq

Abraço!